# My Function is taking far too long and causing the page to timeout

Tags: php, mysql

We have a new magento store. Magento uses phtml files and "blocks" to display data on the front end.

On the main page of the website, we are displaying all of our products in a tabbed format.

The data is stored in custom tables, containing the store views, the categories, the brands, the ranges, the products and then finally the product options.

to pull all of this data i am currently doing something like:

```
foreach(getCategories(storeview) as cateogry)
    foreach(getBrands(category) as brand)
        foreach(getProducts(brand) as product)
            foreach(getProductOptions(product) as option)
```

and all along the way i am packing these into a single JSON object.

each of the `get` functions is querying the database to pull all of the objects related to the current object that is being iterated over.

is there a php function that i can use which could more efficiently pull all of the data to the front end?

every object that is being pulled is being mapped to the appropriate parent object.

The resultant object looks something similar to this:

```
Category

->brand

  ->range

    ->product

      ->option

      ->option

      ->option

    ->product

      ->option

      ->option

      ->option

    ->product

      ->option

      ->option

      ->option

  ->range

    ->product

      ->option

      ->option

      ->option

  ->range

    ->product

      ->option

      ->option

      ->option
```

Comment: *"all of our products"* How much products?

Comment: You might want to use `JOIN`s in your query to fetch ALL the datas with their relations in **one query**, instead of doing a lot of queries (I suppose `getCategories()`, `getBrands()` and so on are querying the DB)

Comment: @nstanard this is purely for pulling data from the backend to the frontend. I am using Javascript on the front end to display the data.

Comment: @cid , there are around 4 categories, 15 brands, 40 ranges, 200 products and 300 product options

Comment: You're displaying the list of all 200 products or all 300 product options on the main page? You might want to paginate

Comment: "to pull all of this data i am currently doing something like:" Instead of making all the get calls and mapping to a single JSON object... Do the get calls and return all the results independently. Then on the front-end you can map them using JavaScript if you need.

Comment: So, Magento uses blocks. Im not actually making any HTTP requests to return this. It is a part of the page rendering that returns it.

How efficient would it be to break this down into separate HTTP Requests, for example 4, which would be one per category?